# Pyagame 'Return' outside function: Clock Is not defined

Tags: python, pygame

NEW: Since I am here in line 30 it is now telling me clock is not defined
I've been writing some code for a game I'm making for homework and it was
 working until I added some code for music and then suddenly the indent levels were off.
Here is the code:

```
image_x = 0
image_y = 0

while 1:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            return
```

Please ask if you need to see the entire program if need be.
Here's the entire thing, maybye this will help:

```
# This just imports all the Pygame modules
import pygame

class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#soundObj = pygame,mixer.Sound('The Tonight Show Star Wars The Bee Gees Stayin Alive Shortened.mp3')
#soundObj.play()
#import time
#time.sleep(52)


#class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   # def __init__(self, *groups):
       # super(Player, self.__init__(*groups)
        #self.image = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01.png')
       # self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((320, 240), self.image.get_size())

    #def update(self):
       # key = pygame

image = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01.png')

# initialize variables
image_x = 0
image_y = 0

while 1:
clock.tick(60)

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        return
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        return

image_x += 0
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        image_x -= 10
if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        image_x += 10
 if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        image_y -= 10
if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    image_y += 10

    screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
screen.blit(image, (image_x, image_y))
pygame.display.flip()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    pygame.display.set_caption('St.Patrick game')
    Game().main(screen)
```

Comment: Where is the function, then?

Comment: are you maybe using spaces **and** tabs?

Comment: I'm just using tabs.

Comment: in the code pasted here there a spaces in the indentation visible in edit mode

Comment: Not sure if connected to the issue, but did you maybe intend to write a `while True:` - `break` loop instead? This `while 1:`, `return` seems rather dodgy and outright false if there is **no** function around it.

Comment: It may also be the video I was going off of is from 2013.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Using `break` would not work. It would only break control from the nearest loop, the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a `return` statement outside of a function. In your case you can replace them with `pygame.quit()` and `sys.exit()` calls to quit the game.

```
import sys  # At the top of the file.

while 1:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: It worked now it is telling me clock is not defined.

Comment: That happens because you've defined the clock in the `main` method of the `Game` class, so it is a local variable that you can't use outside of the function. Define the `clock` in the global scope. The `Game` class is also pretty much useless here, so I'd just remove it until you are more familiar with object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 2):

Simply a program like this will throw the error in the title:

```
x = 0
if x == 0:
    return
else:
    print("No return")
```

Your indent levels may not be off, it's just that Python doesn't allow return statements outside functions.

Answer (score 2):

`return` is a specific syntactic construct to return control (and an optional value) from a function to the caller. Using it anywhere else wouldn't make sense. What I suspect you actually want to achieve is exiting from your game loop.

This is commonly done by using a *flag*, a variable that switches between to 'yes' or 'no' values. In your case, you need a flag to know when to exit from your game loop:

```
# Set the flag to a 'no' value - False - because
# we don't want to exit right now.
should_exit = False
# Start the game loop, using the flag to let the loop know
# when to exit.
while not should_exit:
    ...
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        # If the user is quitting the game, exit the while
        # loop.
        should_exit = True
```